# How to upload LARGE files on YouTube

Tags: php, upload, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I have tried two methods to upload large files on YouTube but none of them works, each has its own issues, my aim is to find a correct answer to upload large files.

**First Method:**

It chunks the large files into different parts, and rather than sending them separately and upload them at once it uploads them separately. So at the end I have a long list of unloadable different parts of the file on Youtube rather than a single file.

**Code of method 1**

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $videoPath = "path/to/foo.mp4";
  $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
  $snippet->setTitle("Test title2");
  $snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
  $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
  $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

  $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
  $status->privacyStatus = "private";

  $video = new Google_Video();
  $video->setSnippet($snippet);
  $video->setStatus($status);

  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/mp4', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

  $result = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
      array('mediaUpload' => $media));

  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($result, $chunk);
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126330/uploading-large-video-via-youtube-api-causing-out-of-memory) which its answer code is similar to google_mediaFileupload but I am not sure how to use it.

**Second method**

I am also trying to use resumable upload to upload them but when I use the following code it runs into following error:

**Code of method 2**

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_MediaFileUpload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');
$client->setClientId('My Client ID');
$client->setClientSecret('My secret code');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:8888/mymediaapp2/uploadvideo.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('My developer key');
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");
$youTubeService = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
echo "here";
$json = $client->getAccessToken();
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$myvar = "";
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
   if($key == "access_token")
    echo "val is" .$val;
}

    $service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?
    uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status';
    $c = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = array(
        "Authorization" => $val,
        "Content-Length" => '255',
        "Content-Type" => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        "X-Upload-Content-Length" => '30000',
        "X-Upload-Content-Type" => 'video/mov'
    );

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    $curl_resp = curl_exec($c);

    curl_close($c);
    echo $curl_resp;
}else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a href='$authUrl'>upload</a>";
}



?>
```

**Error of method 2**

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login 
Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, 
"message": 
"Login Required" } }
```

**Please note,** I have given 50 bounty to one of the answers for solving one of the issues of the code. Although the problem is not completely solved yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have forgotten to set the API key and you may use resumable upload.

Comment: API key and client id, secret are separate. If you use API key, you can do calls without user date and don't need to use client id and secret. When you use them, you can access both generally available data as well as user data and won't need API key. API key is for simple access.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya so whats your suggestion ?

Comment: If you created your project in dev console correctly, enabled YouTube Data API, used latest client library and copy pasted your client id and secret, that should work. No need for API key. API key is for simple access only (things you won't need to login, like search public videos). I tested example 1, and worked without any problem

Answer (score 0):

You should create a project in your [Dev Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0) and get your client id and secret from that console.

[Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) has all the information.

First, you will start with [Registering your Application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).

Also you can [watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNRMeaz6QRI) for How to Do it.

Comment: I do not get you, would you give me an example or sample code?

Comment: It's not about the code, please read this document and apply each step before the code. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: good one but does not solve the issue

Comment: So you created your project in Dev console and enabled Data AAPI v3 from APIs. Then you used the client id and secret and replaced them inside this code, right? And what's the part that is not working?

Comment: It runs into following error (403) Access Not Configured

Comment: Are you sure, using the same account, you did all the steps above and enabled Data API v3?

Comment: Also this video can help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNRMeaz6QRI

Comment: Thanks but I have already watched that video and read all the documentations.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) supports Resumable uploads but most of large uploads come from direct upload anyway.

Should be just a matter of setting a parameter in the [constructor of Google_MediaFileUpload](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/service/Google_MediaFileUpload.php#55).

There is an example of usage of the class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465491/post-large-video-to-youtube-via-google-php-client-api-v3), the relevant line is:

```
$media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/mp4', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
```

For authentication, you can use examples like in [this one](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/php/create_broadcast.php).
Try creating installed application and other, use that client id and secret while you are testing locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the example that you have provided is exactly what I am using, the problem of this code is that, it does not put the chunks it post each separately. so at the end I will find a long list of different parts of file on my youtube account. However as each of those is a chunk of the original file, none of them work.

Comment: If you see my example above it sets resumable uploads to true, whereas in previous stackoverflow question it doesn't. If you set that parameter like $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/mp4', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes); it will act as one upload

Comment: Comparing my code with yours and the constructor I could not find any difference with my code. what difference do you refer to ?

Comment: Also why do you suggest me to use installed applications to test?

Comment: If you are testing it locally, you receive the token back, not the webserver

Comment: I used that but still the same issue

Comment: OK, I will test same method and file internally if that's a bug.

Comment: I copy pasted the first method you posted. Included the authentication from https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/php/create_broadcast.php  (first 40 lines). Replaced my client id and secret. It worked well for 15MB mp4 file. No API key set or anything.

Comment: Please make sure, you are using the latest client library from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/